# How to make GRUB2 boot into VeraCrypt bootloader

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub2, veracrypt

I would like to dualboot encrypted Linux with encrypted Win7(VeraCrypt).
I want to have GRUB2 in the MBR, it would let me choose Win/Linux, and if I chose Win I would go into VeraCrypt bootloader to unlock it. However I have no idea how to chain it like this.

Could you help me please?

Thanks